# Export Datawindow to excel in powerbuilder

Tags: excel, powerbuilder, datawindow

I want to export all columns in a data window to excel in power builder.
After I select All the data displayed in a window, then I should export them to excel.

```
    e.g integer li_ret

li_ret = exporttoexcel(dw_excel, 'c:\doc\datawindow.xls')
if li_ret = 1 then
   return 0
else
   return -1
end if
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you asking how to export to Excel? Are you asking for support on this ExportToExcel() function (which isn't part of standard PowerBuilder)? Clarification may help you get what you're after.

Comment: Terry, exporttoexcel()  was just an example function name

Answer (score 0):

The DataWindow function SaveAs() has Excel options. However, it's important to note that SaveAs() with Excel options work against the data set of the DataWindow, not against the presentation layer, so things like format masks, labels and positioning are lost.

If this is good, but you only want to work against selected rows, it wouldn't be a big deal to create a DataStore with the same dataobject, copy the selected data into it and leverage SaveAs().

If you want something fancier, there at least used to be third party products that supported Excel export, or you could roll your own using OLE calls to Excel.

Good luck.